# Add a form to reveal.js presentation

Tags: javascript, php, reveal.js

I would like to add forms to a reveal.js presentation using JSON.

Here is the form embedded in one of the reveal slides:

```
<section>
  <form action="#">
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</section>
```

I also added this PHP script to the top of the file:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file = "data.json";
    json_string = json_encode($_POST,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents($file, $json_string,FILE_APPEND);
}
 ?>
```

I believe the file should be run in as .php extension to properly execute the PHP script which sends the user input to the server, however, I get a white screen when when running revealjs as a .php extension.

Has anyone successfully embedded forms in their revealjs presentation?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have PHP setup and configured properly on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I add form to reveal.js, but I work with javascript, no php.

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/20/

```
<h2>Form</h2>
<section>
  <form action="#">
      First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" data-name="firstname"/><br/>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" data-name="lastname"/><br/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</section>
<h2>JSON</h2>
<p id="json"></p>

    $(function() {
        $('body').on('submit','form',function() {
            var answers = [];
            $('input[type="text"]', this).each(function(){
            answers.push({'name':$(this).data('name'), 'value':this.value});
            });
            var data = {
                'answers': answers
            };
            json = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#json').append(json);
            return false;
        });    
    });
```